# SQL (one to many) исключить все many при условии

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пример данных

```
id pid field

1  1   commissionAmount.amount
2  1   principalAmount.amount
3  2   commissionAmount.amount
4  2   principalAmount.amount
5  3   commissionAmount.amount
```

Есть условная таблица event_log и таблица event_log_items(выше), в которой pid указывает на event_log id.

Я хочу написать выборку, в которую попадут записи event_log, у которых в event_log_items нету записей со значением field = 'principalAmount.amount' и обязательно есть запись со значением field = 'commissionAmount.amount'.

В результате верного sql, в данном примере должен быть выбран только один ряд с id = 5, т.к. у pid = 3 есть запись только с commissionAmount.amount.

Использую Postgres

Comment: *должна выбраться только запись с id = 5.* Это почему же? запись с id = 2, у еённой папы (id=1) нет никакого "principalAmount.amount", так что и она тоже должна быть выбрана.

Comment: Папы - это pid. Есть 3 элемента в event_log,  у них 5 дочерних в event_log_items. Я хочу выбрать только те записи event_log, у которых в event_log_items есть interestAmount и нету principalAmount. В данном случае это только элемент с id = 5.

Comment: Вы сперва хорошо подумайте, что же Вам на самом деле надо. У указанной мной записи - есть "principalAmount.amount", но нет такого у родителя. А запрета на это значение у самой записи я в вопросе в упор не вижу. Откорректируйте свой вопрос так, чтобы НИКАКИХ подобных недосказанностей в принципе не было.

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим способом:

```
WITH event_data AS (SELECT el.id as eid,
                           elc.id,
                           elc.field
                    FROM eventlog as el
                    INNER JOIN eventlog_items as eli ON el.id = eli.event_id
                    WHERE field = 'commissionAmount.amount'
                       OR field = 'principalAmount.amount'),

     event_data_p AS (SELECT id, event_id as eid
                      FROM eventlog_items
                      WHERE field = 'principalAmount.amount')
SELECT ed1.id,
       ed1.eid,
       ed1.field
FROM event_data as ed1
LEFT JOIN event_data_p as ed2 ON ed1.eid = ed2.eid
WHERE ed2.id IS NULL;
```